# Get matching substring in MySQL SELECT ... LIKE

Tags: mysql, select, substring, sql-like

In MySQL, when querying tables with large pieces of text with

```
SELECT textcol FROM manytexts WHERE textcol LIKE "%interesting % bit%";
```

how can I get back only the matching bit in textcol?

E.g. from

> "blah blah blah interesting green bit blah blah blah"

Expected Result:

> "interesting green bit"

Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime I realised that obviously in a query "%interesting % bit%" the whole record is a match because of the opening and trailing %. So of course any other construction that gets me to the expected result is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is another way, but you could use `SUBSTR`, `INSTR` and `LENGTH`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(field, 1, INSTR(field, 'bit') + LENGTH('bit') - 1)
FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTR(YourField, INSTR(YourField, 'interesting'), LENGTH(YourField)) field
  FROM YourTable
  ) t
```

And here is the Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/539b6/2

Good luck.

Comment: you should limit your inner select (e.g. `FROM YourTable WHERE YourField LIKE '%interesting bit%'`) or you're going to get a lot of empty rows...